# Flask-SQLAlchemy - how to add bind key to existing database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

Due to additional data, I decided to reorganize the original SQLAlchemy database and start using multiple databases.  Is there a way of changing the table name and adding a bind key to the original database?
I searched through SQLAlchemy Migrate's documentation but I couldn't find anything.
Thanks.

Comment: have u try this: $ flask db init --multidb, More details https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Bind keys are a flask-sqlalchemy-specific thing and is not stored in the database. There's nothing to migrate.